# How to implement Chained payment of paypal in laravel

Tags: laravel, paypal, chained-payments

We have develop an application which work as platform between Customer and merchants of various fields. In this application customer purchase product or service from merchants or vendors and make payment through paypal. Now I want to implement commission of owner of application for each transaction made from customer to merchants. That is fix percent of total payment paid by customer to merchant. below is image which shows what functionality i require in my application.

[image]

For example Sender pay $100 in our application then as owner i got $10 as commission and $45 is transfer to each merchant or if single merchant then $90 will be transfer to merchant's paypal account. Can anyone please help me to implement this in laravel

Comment: You can read paypal documentation... https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: Adaptive Payments is no longer available for new apps.  It's being replaced with the "PayPal for Partners" system, but that is not ready for all yet.  It's in closed beta.  For now, you can look at [this article](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-split-payments-express-checkout-billing-agreements-reference-transactions/) for potential options.